# can we upload image and video directly to Facebook using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I'm new with phone gap please give me tutorial link for Facebook image and video upload from gallery or recorded from camera.Thnks

Comment: Yes please read more about using [Phonegap Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap (now Cordova) has an officially supported Facebook plugin that can be found here: https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect

It offers complete integration with FB API, so you can accomplish regular tasks such as image upload.